# Parsing numbers from different cultures in C#

Tags: c#, culture

I'm writing some code to parse a string into a double, but this string is passed to me from another machine. Naturally a problem has occurred where the culture may be different. So, while machine A might send me:

```
"0.5"
```

Machine B might send me

```
"0,6"
```

Because it's in Germany and has a different culture.

What's the best way to correctly parse both of these inputs? Someone suggested using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as an argument to `Convert.ToDouble` but won't that only help where **I'm** producing the above strings, not when someone else can send me different ones?

Am I right in thinking I'll need to know the source culture and change `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to match before attempting to convert?

Comment: It is not because it is in germany, it is becaus the programmers were ignorant to the issue - sadly well too common. Alll outside communication should be in the INVARIANT culture. FxCop even warns abvout that in .NET when you do String.Format.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I understand better now the use of the invariant culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a machine or a person that's sending this? If it's a machine - that is to say, there's an application on another machine that decides what data to send rather than it being a "blind" transmission of user input, then the format for such things should be specified rather than locale-dependent. Generally this means you both agree to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or a culture equivalent to that if the other application is not .NET.

If it's a person and you know their locale, then you can use `double.Parse(decString, cultureInfo)`. This can fail if e.g some English-speaking person borrows their German-speaking friend's computer.

If you know there won't be any grouping separators (e.g. 123,456.78 or 123'457,78) then you can use `double.Parse(decString.Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but can't if there's groupings as that means `123,456.78` becomes `123.456.78`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the background I needed to grasp the problem and now I understand properly why people use the invariant culture.

Comment: Yes, the InvariantCulture is not really a culture at all. It's for doing the same sort of operations (displaying a number as a string, etc.) in a way that deliberately hides cultural differences because it's only machines involved.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the source culture, and can get a `CultureInfo` instance representing it, you can pass this to the `Convert.ToDouble` or `Double.Parse` method as a parameter. For instance, if you have this from a (known) German user:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
double result = Double.Parse("0,5", cultureInfo);
```

If you're not sure, but have a limited range of source cultures, then you could use a number of `Double.TryParse` attempts with the various cultures. However, as has been pointed out below, "1,000" could have quite different meanings depending on the culture...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to parse the numbers reliably you'll need to know the source culture.

Answer (score 0):

The best situation is when sender and receiver always use the same Culture for transmitting data. In your current case: even the german machine should send "0.5".

The next best thing in theory, is to adjust the receiver's settings to conform to the sender's settings. Although in practice this is harder than the previous case: without the sender cooperation, it's impossible to exactly identify the culture. And when you can make the sender to cooperate, you are better off to force it into sending the culture you want. So you barely ever see this in practice.

If you do NOT control the source, the only option left is trying to detect the culture, adjust your parsing, and hope it works. Expect it to be a constant source of bugs, though.

---

So the best thing to do, is to settle on a culture (usually `InvariantCulture`) and adjust the sender. You will be better off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the background regarding keeping the culture the same between sender/receiver.