# C# Number format dealing with digit grouping

Tags: c#, numbers, cultureinfo

I encountered an issue with C# (and Java) on the parsing/validation of culture-sensitive numerical formatting. It seems like when it comes to digit grouping, the separator can be placed anywhere in .NET. Is there a way to enforce a strict adherence of the usage of the digit grouping? For instance, see the following:

```
Decimal.Parse("9,0"); /// Returns 90, which is wrong
Decimal.Parse("90,00"); /// Returns 9000, which is wrong
Decimal.Parse("9,000"); /// Returns 9000, which is right
```

To complicate things, cultures differ in the number of digits per group.

Any suggestions?

Edit: It was suggested I add CultureInfo into the Parse(), but that does not work properly still. For instance:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); /// Murican English
Double.Parse("9,0", culture); /// Returns 90 when it should throw an exception

culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"); /// Brazillian Portuguese
Double.Parse("9.0", culture); /// Returns 90 when it should throw an exception
```

Comment: You should pass a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, but my issue is slightly different to the context that you guys are speaking of.

Comment: For a parser, when `"9,000" == 9000` then `"9,0" == 90`. The grouping-by-3 is only enforced on output. What would like to see for `"9,0"` : an error or `9` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find information on parsing in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w.aspx) as use `CultureInfo culture` as seen in the example in the link

for example

```
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
number = Double.Parse(value, culture);// 1,304.16 --> 1304.16
```

but "en-US" can't parse "1 304,16". "fr-FR" can --> you'll get  1304.16

Answer (score 0):

You should specify *CultureInfo*, since parsing results are *culture dependent* e.g.

```
  // English, United States: 
  // "," is a thousand but not decimal separator, decimal separator is "." 
  // d1 = 90 since "," is NOT a decimal separator
  Decimal d1 = Decimal.Parse("9,0", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // <- 90 

  // Russian, Russia:
  // "," is a decimal separator
  // d2 = 9.0 since "," is a decimal separator
  Decimal d2 = Decimal.Parse("9,0", new CultureInfo("ru-RU")); // <- 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For correctly parsing the numbers you definetly need the Source Culture Info of the number.
Refer this 
[Parsing numbers from different cultures in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909263/parsing-numbers-from-different-cultures-in-c-sharp)